# Как лучше сказать: "этого" или "это"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Он хотел сделать нечто, *но этого (это) почему-то не получалось*" - как лучше сказать: "этого" или "это"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне больше нравится вариант "это". Разница между "этого" и "это" в том, что в одном случае местоимение является подлежащим, а в другом случае - зависимым от сказуемого слова. Сами задайте вопросы к словам. Получается, разница в смысле. В одном случае, делается ударение на то, что *не получается*, а в другом, что именно данное *нечто* не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Грамматически одинаково возможно, стилистически - весьма сомнительно.

На мой взляд "не получалось" скорее "это", особенно если нет сопутствующих слов.
Но фраза все равно не очень симпатичная.
Перво-наперво надо бы как-то выделить смысловую нагрузку "этого".
"Он хотел сделать нечто, но именно это почему-то не получалось"
или
"Он хотел сделать нечто, но это-то почему-то не получалось".

Вот если там не "нечто", а что-то конкретное...
Тогда однозначно "это":
"Он хотел сунуть ключ в замочную чкважину, но это почему-то не получалось".

"Этого" будет скорее в другом варианте:
"Он хотел сунуть ключ в замочную скважину, но почему-то не смог этого сделать".

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, здесь уместен родительный падеж, то бишь *"этого"*.

Answer (score 0):

Есть известное правило о том, что глагол с частицей НЕ управляет родительным падежом существительного, особенно если это существительное обозначает какое-то отвлеченное понятие. Значит, правильно "этого"

Comment: Нет правила, что это правило надо применять там, где глагол ничем не управляет.

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не сказать так: "Он хотел сделать нечто, но почему-то не получалось"? Смысл сохранён, а "воды" поменьше.